# How to build swipe view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewController and when I click on it, it will show a DetailViewUIController.
I want to add a functionality which when I am in DetailViewUIController and I swipe to right, it will show the DetailViewUIController of next item and when left, it will show the previous item.

I find a link which kind of do that in swift. But it only has 3 static subviewcontroller.
https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swipe-view-with-swift-44fa83a2e078

The number of entries in my TableView can be pretty long, how can I do the same thing dynamically, i.e. without having static number of subviewcontroller created and add as 'addChildViewController'?

Update:

Thanks again @rdelmar for your help.

I am having trouble getting the ' set the contentOffset of the collection view to (collection view width) * selectedRow' to work.

In my prepareForSegue function, I have added:

```
  x = Float(indexPath.row) * 375.0
  var point = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x), 0)
  println ("***x=")
  println (x)
  detailController.collectionView?.setContentOffset(point , animated: false)
```

where detailController is UICollectionViewController.

and in the

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DetailViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        println("DetailViewController in cellForItemAtIndexPath()")
        println(indexPath.row)
     cell.myitem = allItems[indexPath.row]
```

return cell
   }

And I always see cellForItemAtIndexPath trying to get 0th element of the allItems (that is the whole collections of all my objects.

So setContentOffset() does not change what I am displaying in the Detail View regardless which item I click in my TableView to launch the Detail View.

Any idea to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this. One way would be to make your detail view controller's view be a collection view (with paging enabled), whose cells are the same size as the screen. You would need to pass in the array that you use to populate your table so the collection view could populate its cells. This would be quite efficient, since the collection view would only ever need to instantiate two cells.

Comment: Thanks. I create a CollectionViewController and XCode creates a CollectionView inside the CollectionViewController in the StoryBoard. But by default, the cell size is 50 X 50. How can I make the cell the same size as the screen?

Comment: @hap497, You can just drag the corner in the storyboard, or set the size in the size inspector for the collection view.You can also set it in code with the itemSize property.

Comment: Thanks, again. One more question. User can click the 5th element in my tableview to launch the Detail View. How can my detail view controller's view be a collection view jump to the 5th element when it first launch? and swipe left will show 6th?

Comment: @hap497, you'll have to pass the selected row number as well, and set the contentOffset of the collection view to (collection view width) * selectedRow.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am still struggling in setting the cell size to same size as screen. I have edited my question.

Comment: @hap497, you should edit your question, not my answer if you want to add what you've done now. Why make the cell 600X600? That's not the size of an iPhone or an iPad, so paging won't work properly. You need to make the cell the same size as the collection controller's view. As to why your label isn't centered, what constraints do you have on the view you added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61531/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-hap497).